# Get class object from spring bean name

Tags: java, spring

I'm having trouble finding the Class of a spring bean. The only information I currently have is the bean id.

Given in my application context I have the following bean:

```
 <bean id="someConfig" class="com.foo.bar.GenericConfig">
```

I currently only have the name of the class "someConfig". How do I obtain the Class from the bean name? Is there any way of doing this without using ApplicationContext.getBean()?

Ideally I want to be able to do something like this:

```
Class<?> clazz = getClass("someConfig");
```

Comment: Why are you wanting to do this?

Comment: I'm using reflection to set a series of properties in different classes. With reflection, I can only obtain the bean id name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see in the [javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/BeanFactory.html#getType-java.lang.String-) there is a method `getType` which returns the class.

> getType
>   Class getType(String name)
>             throws NoSuchBeanDefinitionException
>
> Determine the type of the bean with the given name. More specifically,
>   determine the type of object that getBean(java.lang.String) would
>   return for the given name.  For a FactoryBean, return the type of
>   object that the FactoryBean creates, as exposed by
>   FactoryBean.getObjectType().
>
> Translates aliases back to the corresponding canonical bean name. Will
>   ask the parent factory if the bean cannot be found in this factory
>   instance.
>
> Parameters:
>
> name - the name of the bean to query
>
> Returns:
>
> the type of the bean, or null if not determinable
>
> Throws:
>
> NoSuchBeanDefinitionException - if there is no bean with the given
>   name
>
> Since:
>
> 1.1.2
>
> See Also:
>
> getBean(java.lang.String), isTypeMatch(java.lang.String,
>   org.springframework.core.ResolvableType)